# Unity - Display array of Objects in inspector

Tags: unity, c#

I have an array of `ScritableObject`'s, which should only be displayed in the inspector if a `boolean` is true. How would I do this? With my current code, I get an error saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Tile` to `Tile[]

This is my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEditor; 
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu (fileName="Data", menuName="Tiles/Map", order=1)] 
public class Tile : ScriptableObject {

    public ETile eTile;     
    public Sprite sprite;

    [Space(5), Header("Variety")]   
    public bool variety;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]     
    public float varietyChance;
    public Tile[] varietyTiles; <---- This should be hidden if variety is true 
}

public enum ETile {
    Water, 
    Grass
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(Tile))]
public class MyScriptEditor : Editor {

    override public void OnInspectorGUI() {
        var tile = target as Tile;

        tile.variety = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Hide Fields", tile.variety);

        if (tile.variety) {
            tile.varietyTiles = (Tile)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Tile", tile, typeof(Tile), allowSceneObjects: true);         }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, small modification to Tim C. The line:

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(tileProperty, includeChildren:true)
```

Would in this case always return `false`, therefor the if-statement is never run, which makes that the `ApplyModifiedProperties` method of the `serializedObject` is never called. Making that the value of the new property is never stored in the `tile.varietyTiles`. Therefor, the correct code would be:

```
tile.variety = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Enable", tile.variety);
if (tile.variety) {
    SerializedProperty tileProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("varietyTiles");
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(tileProperty, includeChildren: true);
    if(tileProperty.hasChildren)
    {
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

This code first checks whether you want to display the property or not. After that, on line 3 and 4, it receives the value of the current property and generates a new property with the values of the old one. In the if-statement, it's check whether and `tileProperty` contains children. If `true`, the value of the `tile.varietyTiles` is updated with the new content of `tileProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with ObjectField because Arrays are not Objects. You need to use a PropertyField instead of an ObjectField, which is more generic and can handle properties of any type.

Corrected code:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyTile))]
public class MyScriptEditor : Editor
{

    override public void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var tile = target as MyTile;

        tile.variety = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Hide Fields", tile.variety);

        if (tile.variety)
        {
            SerializedProperty tileProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("varietyTiles");
            if(EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(tileProperty, includeChildren:true))
            {
                serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Returns error: "Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.Object` to `Tile[]`"

Comment: Fixed and updated.

Comment: Kind of fixed. If I try this, the array keeps getting cleared, beause it instantiates a new array